# Show if $\operatorname{Im}(f)$ is an interval, then $f$ is continuous.

Tags: real-analysis

Question: Let $f: E \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. Prove that if $E=(a,b)$ is an open interval and $f$ is monotone, then $f$ is continuous if and only if the image of $f$ is an interval.

General outline of my work:

"$\Leftarrow$"Assume $\operatorname{Im}(f)$ is an interval.

Define $f(x)=y$ for $x\in E$ and let $y\in (f(a),f(b))=\operatorname{Im}(f)$.

For $\epsilon>0$ defined as $\epsilon=\min\{|f(a)-y|,|f(b)-y| \}$, then $y\in (y-\epsilon, y+\epsilon)$.

Then for all $\epsilon>0$ there exists $\delta>0$ such that for $c\in E$,  $|f(x)-f(c)|<\epsilon$ whenever $|x-c|<\delta$. Thus, $f$ is continuous.

Comments:

I don't think I can guarantee $|f(x)-f(c)|<\epsilon$, and I feel like I'm getting lost in my work.

Can someone give me a push in the right direction? No full solutions, please.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

the crucial point is to observe that a discontinuity is a jump.

Show that the left and right limits exist at every point. Then relate the 
continuity property to their agreement and the fact that there are no gaps in the image.